# SQLDatabaseKit - using langchain, Class module error

Tags: python, databricks, langchain, sql-agent

Getting
ValidationError: 1 validation error for SQLDatabaseToolkit
llm
value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict).

Please suggest what am I missing. Thank you

```py
import torch
from transformers import pipeline, AutoTokenizer,AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM,AutoModelForCausalLM
from langchain.agents import create_sql_agent
from langchain.agents.agent_toolkits import SQLDatabaseToolkit
from langchain.sql_database import SQLDatabase

#define model and tokenizer
model_name = "databricks/dolly-v2-12b"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
#model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("databricks/dolly-v2-12b", device_map="auto", torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16)

#initialize the sql database
db = SQLDatabase.from_databricks(catalog="samples", schema="nyctaxi")

#initialize the sql database with huuginface mode.
toolkit = SQLDatabaseToolkit(llm=model, db=db)

#create the SQl agent with hugging face model and toolkit
agent = create_sql_agent(llm=model, toolkit=toolkit, verbose=True)

#run the sql
query ="What is the longest trip distance and how long did it take?"
response=agent.run(query)

#print the response
print(response)
```

Comment: try changing toolkit = SQLDatabaseToolkit(db=db)

Comment: class langchain.agents.agent_toolkits.sql.toolkit.SQLDatabaseToolkit[source]
Bases: BaseToolkit

Toolkit for interacting with SQL databases.

Create a new model by parsing and validating input data from keyword arguments.

Raises ValidationError if the input data cannot be parsed to form a valid model.

param db: langchain.utilities.sql_database.SQLDatabase [Required]
param llm: langchain.schema.language_model.BaseLanguageModel [Required]

Comment: The syntax demands 2 params.  LLM and DB both to be passed.  It looks like with dolly_v2_12b model doesn't seems to be ideal for generating the SQL syntax but only supports contextual response.